# Laravel factory wrapping quotes around data when inserting to db

Tags: laravel, mariadb, factory

I'm using a model factory to populate a model `CouponRule`:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class CouponRuleFactory extends Factory
{

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'coupon_id' => 286,
            'coupon_rule_type_id' => 8,
            'data' => "{'min': 100}",
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now(),
        ];
    }
}
```

When I create a new instance using `CouponRule::factory()->create()`, the data value is being wrapped in quote marks in my database:

```
"{'min': 100}"
```

The data field is defined as `text()`:

```php
Schema::create('coupon_rules', function (Blueprint $table) {
    //...
    $table->text('data');
   //...
});
```

I've confirmed that it *is* wrapped with quote marks (and not just how the db tool - DataGrip - is rendering it) by checking with the MariaDB CLI and by removing the quote marks from the value directly in the db - which leads to it being shown as intended.

Versions:

- MariaDB 10.7.3.
- Laravel 8.83.18

Comment: what's the question ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a NoSQL concept where you can nest an object inside of a column. you can still do it in SQL but you have to write it in JSON encoded format at your server-side (wrapped in "") in LARAVEL you can just decode it using json_decoce($value) to obtain and get the value